# Visa required for Indians for Malaysia during transit flight time

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, malaysia, kuala-lumpur

Planning for a trip from India to Thailand through Kuala Lumpur, the connecting flight from Kuala Lumpur is after 20 hours. Do we need a Malaysian visa for this time frame, if we need to get out of the airport ?

Comment: We shall be having the reurn tickets as well, in case that is one of the eligibility criteria

Comment: I am from India, holding Indian passport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just returned from the trip. I could not get Malaysian transit visa. There are a list of countires, whose visa if we have, then the transit visa will be given to us. We had to spend time inside the KL airport until our flight to Thailand.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kln.gov.my/web/che_berne/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa-for-citizens-of-indian-sub-continental-countries?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fche_berne%2Fother_information

TRANSIT WITHOUT VISA FOR CITIZENS OF BANGLADESH, PAKISTAN, INDIA AND SRI LANKA (INDIAN SUB CONTINENTAL COUNTRIES)

```
CONDITIONS FOR APPROVAL OF TRANSIT WITHOUT VISA FACILITY
1. Transit Without Visa (TWOV) facility is not offered other than to Indian Sub-Continental Countries citizens.
2. TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not possess visa from 3rd country of destination as follows:
   · Australia
   · New Zealand
   · United States of America
   · Japan
   · China
   · Taiwan
   · South Korea
3. TWOV facility cannot exceed more than 120 hours (5 days).
4. TWOV facility is not available at entry point other than Kuala Lumpur International Airport (KLIA) and Low Cost Carrier Terminal (LCCT).
5. TWOV cannot be offered to passenger sponsored by airlines other than Malaysia Airlines and Air Asia. At present only MAS and Air Asia have agreed and accepted all terms and conditions imposed by the Malaysian Government.
6. TWOV cannot be given to visitors who do not fulfil the following:
   · Valid national passport or internationally recognized travel document;
   · Travel documents valid for more than six (6) months from the date of entry;
   · A return ticket to country of origin;
   · Not listed in the Immigration Department’s suspected list.
7. There will be no extension of TWOV facility.
8. Permanent resident and long term pass holder are not bound to any of the TWOV regulations and condition stipulated above.
```